# Embedded For Loops while using range

Tags: python

I would like the following commands to grab the date from the address in this range but I can't seem to get it to run more than once. I am using Python 3. As you can see below the the url for the site is appended with i as to be read http://zinc.docking.org/substance/10 ; http://zinc.docking.org/substance/11 ... and so on.   Here is the code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
site = "http://zinc.docking.org/substance/"
for i in range(10, 16): 
    site1 = str("%s%i" % (site, i))
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(site1).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
    table1 = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "substance-properties"})
for row in table1.findAll('tr'):
    row1 = row.findAll('td')
ate = row1[0].getText()
print(ate)
```

This is my output:

```
$python3 Reset.py
November 11th, 2005
```

The script should however give me 3 dates. This code works so I know that row[0] does in fact contain a value.I feel like there is some sort of simple formatting error but I am not sure where to begin troubleshooting. When I format it "Correctly" this is the code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv
site = "http://zinc.docking.org/substance/"
for i in range(10, 16): 
    site1 = str("%s%i" % (site, i))
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(site1).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
    table1 = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "substance-properties"})
    table2 = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "protomers"})
    for row in table1.findAll('tr'):
        row1 = row.findAll('td')
        ate = row1[0].getText()
        print(ate)
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Reset.py", line 14, in <module>
ate = row1[0].getText()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The first code works so I know that row[0] does in fact contain a value. Any ideas?

Comment: please check the code you've pasted, it doesn't match the traceback

Comment: in every case, you need to check `if row1` before access an index 0, or `len(row1)>0` to access index 1 ...

Comment: The fact that the first code worked simply tells you that `row[0]` contains a value for the *last* row. The second code would need that to be true for *all* rows.

Comment: @PRMoureu I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: @JohnColeman are you saying that if would have to be true for all rows on each site?

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`means you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist, you can add an if test before to make sure

Comment: @PRMoureu Correct, but maybe I am confused as to why this works in the first code and not in the second. JohnColeman suggest that it would have to be true for all rows, I am unsure what he means by this.

Comment: your indentation is different in the 2 codes, the second for loop will run only for the last site requested in the first, and for all of them in the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you first enter the loop you are finding all 'td' elements. The header of the table will not contain any as they are 'th' so the returned list has a length of 0 which is why you get index out of range. You also need to verify that the table does not return a NoneType (and I do not know what you are doing with table2 based on the code you put but the check should be the same):

```
if table1 is not None:
    for row in table1.findAll('tr'):
        row1 = row.find_all('td')
        if len(row1) != 0:
            ate = row1[0].getText()
            print(ate)
```

Comment: martinB0103 Thank you